# Does waitany(Array) actually 'set' a event, or does it just return the index of a signaled event

Tags: c#, multithreading, msdn, autoresetevent

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdykks7z.aspx

According to the docs the return value is:

> "The array index of the object that satisfied the wait."

So that means the index represents a event that has been set and this code would cause a deadlock becuase it would be waiting on itself:

```
    private static AutoResetEvent waitLock()
    {
        //Wait for any of the events to be signaled 
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent;
        lock(yahooRequests)    //Note: yahoo requests is a array of auto reset events
        {
            int index = AutoResetEvent.WaitAny(yahooRequests);
            autoEvent = yahooRequests[index];
            autoEvent.WaitOne();
        }
        return autoEvent;
    }
```

And this code would be correct:

```
private static AutoResetEvent waitLock()
{
    //waitany returns the index of a successfull wait. So this line returns the reference to a autoresetevent.
    return yahooRequests[AutoResetEvent.WaitAny(yahooRequests)];
}
```

I just want to make sure since (in my humble opinion) the documentation is not 100% clear

**EDIT:**

My design was flawed I should have been using a semaphore as @Hans Passant pointed out. Since I wanted to ensure N number of yahooRequests had access to a function. But @arno technically answers the initial question. Really wish I could set two accepted asnwers

**EDIT:**

Also as @Sriram Sakthivel pointed out in the comments the first example would wait on itself forever. But is not actually deadlock.

Comment: Why would you assume former version to deadlock? It just waits again till some other thread signals

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Because waitany would return a index of a successful wait. Then I am pulling that index and waiting again on the SAME thread but never signaling.

Comment: @user975911, why do you want to wait on the same auto-reset event twice in a row? Do you expect it to be signalled twice from another thread?

Comment: @user975911 I dont want to wait twice and I dont think another thread would signal. The first bit of code was my attempt to show a example that would wait forever.

Comment: Yes that would wait forever if never signaled again. but that is not a deadlock. Deadlock means two threads waiting for each other to complete. which will never going to happen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WaitHandle.WaitAny` method does **not** set an event. It returns the *array index of the object that satisfied the wait.* This may need a wait or may also occurr when the event was set before the call to `WaitAny`was done. The index will be returned without wait in the latter case.

Answer (score 2):

> So that means the index represents a event that has been waited on

No, all events in the array were waited on.  The returned index is simply the first one that was Set().  It will be reset after WaitAny() returns.  So the first snippet indeed makes no sense, you don't want to call WaitOne() again.  The second snippet doesn't make much sense, there isn't anything distinctive about the AutoResetEvent object you return.  In particular it isn't signaled anymore since an ARE automatically resets itself.  You really do need to know the index to know which particular job got done.

Comment: I edited my question I was using 'wait' instead of set. Regarding your response. What If I dont care what response is complete I just want to make sure no more than N number of yahooRequests are performing at any point. This function is to inform the caller that 'Yes you can make a request and when your done signal to someone waiting'

Comment: That's completely the wrong way to do that.  You use a Semaphore to limit the number of concurrent requests.

Comment: You are 100% right. Initially I avoided using a semaphore because I mistakenly thought that I would not be able to release it in a async callback (I thought they needed to be released on the thread that waited on it.) Thank you.